# Download the file as PDF using GAS Content Service

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api

I want to download the file as PDF from the Drive using a webapp

But the PDF gets corrupted each time, it works well for https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jrDKkk6uC0qx_XzqFHb4Bo1enZzB-YFv/view?usp=sharing
But this same function doesnt work for https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LFnQHb5C2g4zWGBXsbzKKB1C6OMgQGzi/view?usp=sharing

```
function doGet(e) {
    var id = "1LFnQHb5C2g4zWGBXsbzKKB1C6OMgQGzi"
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
    return ContentService.createTextOutput().setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.PDF).setContent(DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getDataAsString())
    .downloadAsFile("file.pdf")
}
```

Comment: Please read the question, I am willing to accomplish using Content service. The content service must render a PDF. Makes sense?

Comment: I dont want to expose the drive link anywhere in the webapp, so I use content service to fetch a drive file to the front end user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced a situation like yours. I wanted to download files straight from  GDrive without sharing a link through a **Google Web App**. Unfortunately,
**GAS ContentService** provides us with a few mime-types like CSV, JAVASCRIPT, JSON, VCARDS, and TEXT only; Thus, the way I've found to download files like **.PDF** and **.XLSX** without exposing the path to GDrive is by retrieving the **Blob version** of the file converted into a **Base64Encoded** String that you'll export to **ContentService**. You can do that using the method **Utilities.base64Encode** in GAS within **doGet** method.

```
strBase64Encoded = Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
return ContentService.setContent(strBase64Encoded).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
```

That's the way you can export your file on GAS. However, if you want the download starts instantly, you cannot use ContentService but **HTMLService**. You have to create a HTML output having a javascript code that will convert the base64encoded string into your file! We can do that by creating a pseudo anchor.

```
const blob             =  DriveApp.getFileById("your_file_ID").getBlob();
const strBase64Encoded = Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());

const html = `
<script>
  const rawdata        = "${strBase64Encoded}";
  const base64ToDecode = atob(rawdata);
  const bytesArr       = new Array(base64ToDecode.length);
  for (i = 0; i < base64ToDecode.length; i++){
      bytesArr[i] = base64ToDecode.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  const bytes4Blob     = new Uint8Array(bytesArr)
  const blob           = new Blob([bytes4Blob],{"type":"application/pdf"});
  const downloadLink   = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.href    = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  downloadLink.download = "filename.pdf";
  downloadLink.click(); // this will start the download instantly! 
</script>
`;
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

The second url returns "No preview available. File is in owner's trash". Try moving the file out of the trash.